# Turn on core/crash dumps programmatically

Tags: c, linux

I know I can run
"ulimit -c unlimited"

In the shell to turn on core dumps for the current user. 
What I am wondering is how can I do this programmatically from C?

I see there is a ulimit call, but it's been deprecated in favour of get/setrlimit.
What I want to know is what is the equivalent call to setrlimit that would allow crash dumps
to be generated?

Comment: Doh, trust me to read through the man page too quickly.  RLIMIT_CORE is what I was wanting.  cheers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a working solution.  The core files are now being created.

```
struct rlimit core_limit;
core_limit.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
core_limit.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;

if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &core_limit) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "setrlimit: %s\nWarning: core dumps may be truncated or non-existant\n", strerror(errno));
```

Credit goes here: http://adamrosenfield.com/blog/2010/04/23/dumping-core/

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check your current limit for your process than

```
struct rlimit  v;   //you can decelare any variable

getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &v);

printf("softlimit=%d   hardlimit=%d  \n",v.rlim_cur,v.rlim_max);
```

if you want to set new limit than use below code

/////////////////////  set limit //////////////////////////////

lets make it simple

```
struct rlimit v;
v.rlim_cur = 0 ;  //if you do not want the core dump file

/*  v.rlim_cur=RLIM_INFINITY;    //set maximum soft limit of the file(unlimited) */

v.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;    //for reference to the soft limit(unlimited)

setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &v);
```

A value of `rlim_cur` is between 0 and infinity means that core dumps will be generated and truncated to the specified size. This risks creating an incomplete core dump